# Using Overloaded Operator from Abstract Class in Derived Class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class

If I had an abstract class as follows:

```
class Base{
public:
  // some pure virtual functions
  bool operator< (Base &other) const { return str < other.str; }
private:
  string str;
};
```

If the derived class also compares just like the base class (the operator less than function will be the same as the Base class), is it possible to use inheritance or virtual functions to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need to do anything special. The operator is inherited just as any other member function:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
private:
    string str_;

public:
    auto operator<( Base const& other ) const
        -> bool
    { return str_ < other.str_; }
};

class Derived: public Base {};

auto main() -> int
{
    Derived d1, d2;
    d1 < d2;
}
```

---

In passing, note that this operator won't be called by implicit conversion to `Derived` or `Base` of some left side argument.

That's a main reason why binary operators are preferably defined as non-members.

However, also note that as a non-member, if the left formal argument is a reference to non-`const` (as with e.g. `operator<<`), then it needs an rvalue reference version in order to bind to temporary actual argument, if that's desired.

---

A not uncommon way to define an operator as non-member, but inline, is to use the `friend` mechanism, as follows:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Base{
private:
  string str_;
public:
    friend
    auto operator<( Base const &a, Base const& b )
        -> bool
    { return (a.str_ < b.str_); }
};

class Derived: public Base {};

struct Convertible { operator Base () const { return Base(); } };

auto main() -> int
{
    Derived d1, d2;
    d1 < d2;

    Convertible conv;
    conv < d2;
}
```

But note that with this approach the operator can only be found via *argument dependent lookup*, ADL.

Comment: That's the funkiest `main()` I've ever seen ;) +1 for the answer though

Comment: can you explain please your last statement about ADL? Where does ADL kicks in here? `operator<(conv, d2)` is just implicitly converting to `Base` the `conv` object via its `operator Base()`, but where does the ADL comes into play? Ohh I see, you declared it inside `Base`, and won't be find in the global scope...

Comment: @vsoftco: in `conv < d2` the type of `d2` causes a lookup (ADL) in class `Derived` and its base classes. With the given code you can't refer directly to that operator. It isn't a class member, so `Derived::operator<` doesn't refer to it, but neither is it explicitly part of the enclosing namespace, so `::operator<` doesn't refer to it. As written, it's only accessible via ADL. (Well as it turns out VIsual C++ finds it. That's a compiler bug.)

Comment: thanks, didn't read your code carefully and just now I found out you declared it inline.

Answer (score 4):

You will not have to do anything since name lookup will find `operator<` in the base class.
However, it is feasible to define the operator as a non-member `friend` function. I.e.

```
friend bool operator< (Base const& lhs, Base const& rhs)
{
    return lhs.str < rhs.str;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6794b19e37fe5558).

Comment: It's not that one "generally" doesn't have to do anything -- one doesn't have to do anything (strike "generally"). Also, it's not "might be feasible" -- it is feasible (and preferred) to implement binary operators as actual binary functions.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas I (generally) don't like fixed, absolute statements. :o)

Answer (score 0):

I guess a bit of comment/clarification to the post by Mr. Eastwood :) might make sense: since the operator member function does exactly the same in the derived class as in the base class (i.e. compares the same data member), you can just use it as is, without overriding.

The only member functions you HAVE to override are pure virtual functions.

Actually, since this member function is not marked as `virtual`, you wouldn't be able to override it legibly.

Hope that clears things up!